# swagger-ui How do you hide rest methods not implemented

Tags: symfony, swagger-ui

Maybe im just missing it, I would like to hide some rest methods from controllers that do not implement them like options , delete, head

Is there an annotation for this? I could not find it in the documentation 
using https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle v3

currently when i view /api/doc any controllers I add list all rest methods even if I only have a GET method implemented.

[image]

```
<?php

namespace ApiBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;


class UserController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * @Security("is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')")
     * @Route("/api/users", name="get_users", methods={"GET"})
     *
     * @SWG\Response(
     *     response=200,
     *     description="Returns all users"
     * )
     * @SWG\Tag(name="users")
     *
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
     */
    public function getUsersAction()
    {

        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()
             ->getRepository('AccountBundle:User');
        $users = $repo->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();

        return new JsonResponse($users);

    }

}
```

Comment: Well, the reason for you set up interfaces it's to follow and implement all their methods. If your classes are implementing an interface and don't implement all methods, you just doing wrong. Create a simple interface, without those unused signatures and make your classes implement it.

Comment: This class is not implementing an interface

Comment: can you post all your class code?

Comment: updated full class code

Comment: Your code is for `/api/users`, but the screenshot shows `/api/contacts`. Can you update your post so that the code and image refer to the same thing?

Comment: /api/docs shows the api doc swagger for all defined controllers as expected and I just grabbed the first one showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out if you do not specify the methods in the controller in the @Route() annotation then it will show all of them but if you add **methods={}** to the Route annotation then it will only list the defined methods

```
 * @Route("/api/users", name="get_users", methods={"GET"})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Specify **@Value** and **@method** type in the **@RequestMapping**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/instances/all",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@JsonFormat
public String showInstances(){
   return "instances";  
}
```